# vba scan Col & Delete if 0 and then insert row if not equal to next row

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, runtime-error

This is what my data looks like. Its a summary from another sheet.

The code appears to run and do what I need, scan Co B and delete if there is a 0 value, scan Col I and insert row if row below is different, then repeat for Col H. However I get an "runtime 1004 application-defined or object defined error"message instead of the macro just ending. Open to any edits or suggestions

```
Range("A100000").End(xlUp).Activate
Range("N1") = ActiveCell.Row

For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1    
    If Cells(lRow, "b") = 0 Then
        Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Delete                            
    End If
Next lRow

For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1    
    If Cells(lRow, "I") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "I") Then '<~~ debugger highlights this line or the other version of this eq below
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert    
    End If
Next lRow

For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1    
    If Cells(lRow, "H") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "H") Then
        Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert                
    End If
Next lRow

Range("A1").Activate

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
If Cells(lRow, "I") <> Cells(lRow - 1, "I") Then
```

When `lRow` inevitably reached the value of `1` then this is going to cause an error, because

```
lRow - 1
```

is `0` - and there isn't a row number of 0.

---

You need to code for this possibility:

```
For lRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1    
    If Cells(lRow, "I") <> Cells(lRow - IIf(lRow = 1, 0, 1), "I") Then
            Rows(lRow).EntireRow.Insert    
    End If
Next lRow
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Looping forwards would take longer seeing as they're inserting rows ;) Also,  people generally tend to pick things up easier when you use their existing code. That being said I've just introduced an Immediate If into the equation >.<

Comment: Also when running through the next time for column H he would get two lines added for every one that was added when going through column J.  One when lrow with data is not equal to the empty row above and again when the empty row is compared to data above.

Comment: @macroman That worked perfectly. is there any benefit to running this top to bottom. I found that IF statement doing a google search and it happened to work in the other macro I used it.

Comment: the extra inserted row is fine. it helps visually delineate the breaks in the major groups vs the subgroups.

Comment: `IIf()` is _very_ different to `If...Then...` but there's plenty on google for that explanation - just be aware that's all. Whenever you're inserting/deleting rows you should always go bottom-to-top because you are adding/removing row numbers in advance of your variable reaching that number. This will inevitably cause issues.

Comment: Chat blocked ;_; Edit: still dont see how it matters here XD

Comment: [Look here](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4240221/macro-man?tab=profile) just trying to stop OP getting spammed... [Or Here](http://www.themacroman.com/index.php#Contact) Plus I don't fully understand your question...